# BizTalk service to work inside public service

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, biztalk

Maybe someone can enlighten me on this.  And I'm sorry there is no code or images, but there is really not a lot in code that can help at this point.

I have a public service on IIS.  Lets call it iiservice.
And I have a second service on BizTalk.  We'll call that btservice.

My iiservice uses the btservice within its code.

**Here is how I am testing it:**

I have a company computer to test this with.  Since this is supposed to be a public service, I am testing it outside the network.

If I call iiservice outside the network, it can't find btservice; says something like "no endpoint listening to `Biztalk service url`.
If I call iiservice inside the network, it can find btservice.  No problems obviously.

**In conclusion**

How do I get the biztalk endpoint to function/register/listen outside the network?
I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653345/deploying-biztalk-web-service-to-dmz), but it dealt with DMZ and didn't really provide enough information for me to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it's been some time since I asked this question, and I see that there are a couple of people that may have a similar issue.

My solution was to implement a Factory on the IISservice that targeted BTservice.

You can [check out this article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2014/02/23/a-smarter-wcf-service-client-part-3/) to see a tutorial on how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Please contact the network department in the company because the BizTalk Server in the LAN network and is not reachable outside the LAN network, read, the public network.

You have two possibilities

1) Place the BizTalk Server in the [DMZ](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demilitarized_zone_%28informatica%29)

2) Add a rule in the company's firewall that forward HTTP traffic to the BizTalk server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup a reverse proxy with url rewrite in IIS. Have you tried to test the btservice on the machine where the public service is running?